# Getting "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing Route Resolving based on this practices: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y081

But I am getting:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: toursServiceProvider <- toursService <- MainController

My code looks like this:
route-config.js file

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'scripts/partials/home.partial.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        toursService: function(genericData) {
            return genericData.getTours;
        },
        addressService: function(genericData) {
            return genericData.getAddress;
        },
        aboutService: function(genericData) {
            return genericData.getAbout;
        }
    }

})
```

main.controller.js file:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('excursion')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ['toursService', 'addressService', 'aboutService'];

    function MainController(toursService, addressService, aboutService) {

        // vm is our capture variable
        var vm = this;

        vm.tour = toursService.getTours;
        vm.address = addressService.getAddress;
        vm.about = aboutService.getAbout;

    }
})();
```

Comment: Have you included the JavaScript file in which the `toursService` is defined in your `index.html`?

Comment: Does it have to be, I don't think so, take a look at manual.

Comment: If your browser does not load the file, there is no way for Angular to find an initialize the service. Unless you are using something like RequireJS you need to include all AngularJS related JavaScript files using `<script>` tags in your `index.html`.

Comment: It is not a service, just I called it this way and it is just a resolve parameter, that should be injected into controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working, I needed $timeout to make promise available when controller is loaded, here is updated code (just different route, but logic is the same):

```
.when('/tours', {
    templateUrl: 'scripts/partials/pages/tours.partial.html',
    controller: 'TourController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        toursService: function(genericData, $timeout) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                return genericData.getTours;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
})
```